# Making someone a WordPress administrator using PhpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

After database problems on my provider side, I had to reset my admin user password. But then this user was not an admin anymore. In PhpMyAdmin I see that it has a user_status value of 0. How can I make this user an amin in WP dashboard ?

Comment: This is a hosting issue, not a WordPress Issue.

Comment: I'm sorry but I sincerely don't understand your comment.

Comment: @drake035 His comment means that this has nothing to do with WordPress and should not be asked on this website. This question should be moved to another of the stackexchange sites, where it can be answered. We know WordPress around here, we have no special knowledge of PHPMyAdmin or MySQL or general hosting questions.

Comment: I think the question may have been worded a little off but I would say it's definitely a Wordpress-specific question as it's about the organization of the Wordpress user tables.

Comment: How WordPress roles are stored in the database is very WordPress specific. I don’t see how anyone could give an answer without WordPress knowledge.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You actually want to look in the wp_usermeta table.  Once in there, look for the entry that has '`wp_user_level`' in it's 'meta_key' column and has the matching 'user_id' that you would like to update.  Then change that 'meta_value' to 9 or 10.

It is also required to update the '`wp_capabilities`' meta_key value to '`a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}`'

Link to current documentation:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#User_Levels

Comment: It worked thx !! (I'm still struggling with understanding how my question and your answer to it have « nothing to do with WordPress » ...)

Comment: Note at the top: "This article, written to accord with WordPress 1.5, is now obsolete."  Roles and capabilities now http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part.  I've updated my answer to point to the correct user info page.

Comment: This was super helpful and worked to solve an issue my work was having with the "admin" user not actually being an admin and nobody having admin permissions to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

1. Get access with phpMyAdmin to your WordPress database.
2. In phpMyAdmin, click on the tab "SQL" in the top tab bar.
3. Enter this SQL command (with your actual WordPress username instead of `your_username`) and click "Go" to execute it:

   ```
   SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta 
   WHERE meta_key = "wp_user_level" AND user_id = (
     SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta 
     WHERE meta_key = "nickname" AND meta_value = "your_username"
   )
   ```
4. You will see a single-cell table with a `meta_value` column. Double-click that cell and change its value to `10`.
5. Again click the SQL tab, enter this SQL command (with your username instead of `username`) and click "Go" to execute it:

   ```
   SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta 
   WHERE meta_key = "wp_capabilities" AND user_id = (
     SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta 
     WHERE meta_key = "nickname" AND meta_value = "your_username"
   )
   ```
6. Again you will see a single-cell table with a meta_value column. Double-click that cell and change its value to `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`.

(There is a more automated way with SQL `UPDATE` commands instead of the above. Welcome to add it. However, sometimes only executing `SELECT`s and doing the updates manually will feel safer … no strict need for a database backup etc..)